# specific problem involving inheritance and a private object, c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm going to try to make my problem as concise as possible:

I have 3 classes, a robot class, Point class and a world class.

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    void set(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
};

class Robot{
private:
    Point roboLocale;
public:
    Robot()
    {

    }

    void init()
    {
        roboLocale.set(0, 0);
    }

class World
{
private:
    char arr[10][10];
public:
    World()
    {
        std::fill(arr[0], arr[0] + 10 * 10, ' ');

    }
    void injectRobot()
    {
        arr[roboLocale.getX()][roboLocale.getY()] = '@'; // would like to access robotLocales x and y coords
    }

    void displayField()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                std::cout << "[" << arr[i][j] << "]";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    World field;
    Robot robot;
    robot.init();

    field.injectRobot();

    field.displayField();
}
```

In my World class under `void injectRobot()` I am trying to access the `robotLocale` getX() and getY() member functions to 'inject' the robot into my `World::arr`. I simply can not figure out how to do this, or if it's even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `class World : public Robot` are you really sure that your `World` class _is a_ `Robot`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's hard to understand what your question is.

Comment: You probably don't want inheritance but expose the `robot` member variable to be readable with a public getter function, e..g. `const Point & getRobotPosition() const { return robot; }`

Comment: Having a member variable named `robot` inside a `Robot` class, but it's really a `point` that represents a  position... that's a bit confusing.

Comment: @ melpomene I edited the problem in an attempt to make it more explicit

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ If I am returning the robot from a getter do I want to store it in a robot object in my World class??

Comment: "try to make my problem as concise as possible" - That's *too concise*: You told us what you have done, but not what the problem is.

Comment: @BenJenney _"do I want to store it in a robot object in my World class??"_ Sounds reasonable, yes. A `Robot` instance is probably interacting within your `World` model.

Comment: @mkrieger1 tried expressing the problem a little better. Sorry guys, i'm trying. Thank you.

Comment: What is `robotLocale`? That name is not defined anywhere.

Comment: If you mean `roboLocale`, that is a *private* member of the `Robot` class. In `World::injectRobot` there is no `Robot` instance which you can refer to. And even if there were, you couldn't access `roboLocale`, because it's private.

Comment: if I made it protected and tried making the robot a daughter of the world class would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `injectRobot` does not know about any `Robot` instances. How should it know that somewhere else in the program (in your `main`) there is an instance which should be used to fetch the `roboLocale` object which in addition is **private** to the `Robot` class?

1. Your `injectRobot` must has a function parameter where you pass in the `Robot` instance to be injected (or at least its position if that is the only thing you're interested in).
2. Your `injectRobot` muste be able to actually fetch the positional information stored inside that `Robot` object.

You could try:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
private:
    int _x{};
    int _y{};

public:

    // Default constructor to prevent uninitialized values
    Point() = default;

    Point(int x, int y) 
        : _x(x), _y(y) { }

    void set(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    int x() const { return _x; }
    int y() const { return _y; }
};

class Robot 
{
private:
    Point _robolocale;
public:
    Robot() = default;
    Robot(int x, int y) : _robolocale(x, y) {}
    Point const& pos() const { return _robolocale; }
};

class World
{
private:
    char arr[10][10];
public:
    World()
    {
        std::fill(arr[0], arr[0] + 10 * 10, ' ');
    }
    // Which robot should be injected? 
    // We need to pass a robot in because otherwise there is none to inject
    void injectRobot(Robot const& r)
    {
        arr[r.pos().x()][r.pos().y()] = '@'; // would like to access robotLocales x and y coords
    }

    void displayField()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                std::cout << "[" << arr[i][j] << "]";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    World field;
    Robot robot1;
    Robot robot2(7, 4);

    field.injectRobot(robot1);
    field.injectRobot(robot2);

    field.displayField();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it works and mostly makes sense to me. The only thing I am curious about is whether the constant declarations are necessary. Again thank you.

Comment: @BenJenney Try to have everything const unless you really need to modify things.